# Populating tables in Heroku with base data for application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I'm working on an application which uses data from db which has to be populated prior to the application being able to run.  What I have to do is to populate few tables with few thousand rows but I'm not sure how I would do that in heroku because I have limited access to db for loading data.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Regards,
Johann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into [seeds](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding), there's also a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data). I've never used this before, so you may alternately want to…

Create a rake task to suit your specific need. That way you can add the task to your Rails application and run `heroku rake mytask`. Here's a [rake tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data), and a [Railscast on rake tasks](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial) to help get you started.

Answer (score 3):

You can populate a Postgres database locally and then push it to heroku with `heroku db:push` see `heroku help db:push`